# With Spring Data JPA, under what circumstances should I use EntityManager directly?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, entitymanager

Spring Boot Data JPA does an amazing job of generating repositories and abstracting away the managemet of Datasources and EntityManager etc. But sometimes I see code where the EntityManager is included as a field and accessed directly, like in this [Dzone example](https://dzone.com/articles/accessing-the-entitymanager-from-spring-data-jpa)

I don't really understand from that example, when should I include the EntityManager in my class and interact with it directly and when can I just rely on the repository Spring Data JPA autogenerates? Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

One good use of `EntityManager` that I can think of is when you want to get results from a database using complex queries such as join. You can directly query using `EntityManager` and use `ResultTransformer` to get into your custom model.